# Implementing A WordPress Settings Class for Options Pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to implement this class: [A WordPress Settings Class for Options Pages](http://webmaestro.fr/wordpress-settings-api-options-pages/)

What I tried:

```
function add_wp_page(){

  require_once( TEMPLATEPATH."/folder_admin/wm-settings.php" );

  // A top level page
  $my_top_page = create_settings_page(
    'my_top_level_page',
    __( 'My Top Level Page' ),
    array(
      'parent'   => false,
      'title'    => __( 'Top Level Menu' ),
      'icon_url' => 'dashicons-admin-generic',
      'position' => '63.3'
    ),
    array(
      'my_standard_section' => array(
        'title'  => __( 'Standard' ),
        'description' => __( 'My section description.' ),
        'fields' => array(
          'my_input'    => array(
            'label' => __( 'Input example' )
          ),
          'my_checkbox' => array(
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'label' => __( 'Checkbox example' )
          ),
          'my_textarea' => array(
            'type'  => 'textarea',
            'label' => __( 'Textarea example' )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    array(
      'tabs'        => true,
      'submit'      => __( 'My Submit' ),
      'reset'       => __( 'My reset' ),
      'description' => __( 'My page description.' ),
      'updated'     => __( 'My success message !')
    )
  );
  // And a sub-page
  $my_sub_page = create_settings_page(
    'my_sub_page',
    __( 'My Sub Page' ),
    array(
      'parent' => 'my_top_level_page',
      'title'  => __( 'Sub Level Menu' )
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_wp_page' );
```

The TEMPLATEPATH is it ok. If I echo something in wp-settings.php it will print it.

The rest of the code it is from that website. It is from an example.

The menu doesn't show.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings need to be registered before 'admin_init'.

Replace the last line with `add_action( 'init', 'add_wp_page' );`.

Also, avoid wrapping the require_once in an action or you won't be able to access `get_setting()` outside your hook.

Oh, and the position can be a string. And it is actually recommended to use a decimal number to prevent possible conflicts for these menu positions with other plugins or themes.

Comment: Yes ... Thank you. It works now. One question. Where should I put the require if not in an action? Probably because I load it like this the wm-settings.js doesn't load with the right url.

Comment: http://example.com/theme_name/wp-content/plugins/home/x/public_html/name/theme_name/wp-content/themes/theme_name/theme_name_admin/wm-settings.js?ver=4.0. It is taking 2 times my url or something like this. Your answer was right but if you can tell me please where to put the require I will be very grateful. Thank you again. For the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please set a 'position' => '63.3' to **integer**.
or use positions of core menu: 
`2 Dashboard
 4 Separator
 5 Posts
 10 Media
 15 Links
 20 Pages
 25 Comments
 59 Separator
 60 Appearance
 65 Plugins
 70 Users
 75 Tools
 80 Settings
 99 Separator` 
The position in the menu order this menu should appear.
Hope it solves your problems :)

Comment: ok. you not need to call a add_action. because wm-settings.php file already call it when ever you call a function.

Comment: You got solutions or i have another solutions for create a menu in admin.